# How can I add text to a combobox item only when I start a search in my filterable kendo combobox?

Tags: angular, typescript, combobox, kendo-combobox

I need to add a text after an option in my combobox but only when i'm doing a search in it (it's filterable kendo combobox).
my combobox now is like this

```
<my-combobox
  [label]="label"
  [form]="form"
  [name]="'dataset'"
  [filterable]="true"
  [textField]="'desc'"
  [valueField]="'cod'"
  [options]="options"
  [itemDisabled]="itemDisabled"
  [initialValue]="initialValue"
>
</my-combobox>
```

i have to manipulate my options only when i'm searching? there is a way to change template only when i do a search? thanks

i tried to modify my textfield with a 'desc + string' but i don't know how to intercept the research your text

Comment: See https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/events/. You can use the `filterChange` event to manipulate the `options`.